# Delete user id from documents after deleting user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, social-networking

I'm building social network app using nodejs and mongodb. Now in my user schema i have an array of ids of users who are following certain user and ids of users who are followed by certain user. When i delete the user i want to delete his id from all arrays inside of users who are following him. So that if he deletes his accont he is not going to be followed by any user anymore

```
    following: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    followers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose middlewares are used for uses cases similar to yours, you can specify a middleware function to run before a defined operation (here we specify "remove" and the middleware runs before the operation using "pre" here is a simple implementation:

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
{
    username: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        required: true,
    },
    //.....
});

userSchema.pre('remove', async function (next) {
   // remove userid from all following arrays in users collection
   // reference user with "this"
   await userModel.updateMany(
       {
           following: {
               $in: [this._id]
           }
       },
       {
           $pull: {
               following: { _id: this._id }
           }
       });
   // calling next will call next middleware which will delete user
   next();
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. But it seems like this middleware was never reached. When i log to the console 'Removing" from inside it it does not appear. I'm using findByIdAndRemove to remove my docs. Doc is removed but his id is still present in other documents

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.deleteUser = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  await User.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
  const data = await User.updateMany(
    {
      following: {
        $in: [req.params.id],
      },
    },
    {
      $pull: {
        following: req.params.id,
      },
    }
  );
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    data,
  });
});
```

It worked like this. I'm just interested is this the right way.